# Branch and Cut algorithm

Tags: branch-and-cut

[image]

[image]

Could someone please explain what is the point of this added cut? Also how was it deduced?

Could someone please give some examples of this sort? As I've been searching for such examples but did not find any on the internet.

Comment: You have been part of the community and participating in asking questions long enough that you know by now that when questions are posted as images, they are not very searchable. So, please check one of your old questions, click the "edit" under the question, see how others have changed that, and then try to edit your question here.

Comment: Please take the time to post a well-formed question, not an image.

Comment: If your problem is pure integer programming, do you try solving your problem using Gomory fractional cut algorithm?